# Dropdown doesn't appear for dynamically generated datalist

Tags: javascript, html

I have a text input with a datalist that's dynamically populated as the user types.  This seems to work - as I type I see in the DOM inspector that the `datalist` element is being populated with `option`s.  However, the dropdown box that should let the user select an `option` doesn't appear.  Is there some javascript I can use to force it to appear?

```
<html>
    <body>
        <input type="text" name="brand" id="brand_input" list="brand_list" oninput="handleInput(this)" placeholder="Brand">
        <datalist id="brand_list"></datalist>
    </body>
    <script>
        window.addEventListener("load", function() {
            window.inputXHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
        });
        function handleInput(input) {
            var list = input.list;

            window.inputXHR.abort();

            window.inputXHR.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (window.inputXHR.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                    var status = window.inputXHR.status;
                    if (status == 0 || (status >= 200 && status < 400)) {
                        list.innerHTML = "";

                        var resp = JSON.parse(window.inputXHR.responseText);
                        resp.forEach(function(i) {
                            var opt = document.createElement("option");
                            opt.value = i;
                            list.appendChild(opt);
                        });
                        // These two lines fix the issue:
                        document.getElementById("otherelement").focus();
                        input.focus();
                    }
                }
            };

            window.inputXHR.open("GET", "/get_brand/"+input.value, true);
            window.inputXHR.send();
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

e: I found that focusing away from the textbox and then re-focusing fixes the issue.  I added a couple lines in my code above that do that automatically after the datalist is loaded.

Comment: No framework - what about the code doesn't make sense?  Setting `opt.text = i` in addition to `opt.value` doesn't make a difference, if that's what you're referring to.

Comment: Misunderstanding, anyway your code works as is, but suppose XHRs do not work snippets here - made a test mock, but in case there are no CORS, JSON or network problems around, your code works ?? Maybe you need to start typing first or use different event like onfocus, onkeypress, etc. ? In Chrome there is no dropdown arrow till mouse over, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Do not know how/where you get your data, but code seems to work using fake demo data ?

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    window.inputXHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
});
function handleInput(input) {
    var list = input.list;

    window.inputXHR.abort();

    window.inputXHR.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (window.inputXHR.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            var status = window.inputXHR.status;
            if (status == 0 || (status >= 200 && status < 400)) {
                list.innerHTML = "";

                var resp = JSON.parse(window.inputXHR.responseText);
                resp.forEach(function(i) {
                    var opt = document.createElement("option");
                    opt.value = i;
                    list.appendChild(opt);
                });
            }
        }
    };

    window.inputXHR.open("GET", "/get_brand/"+input.value, true);
    window.inputXHR.send();
}

// Mock demo here
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
window.inputXHR = {
    readyState: XMLHttpRequest.DONE,
    status: 200,
    responseText: '["Charles Rolls","Henry Royce"]',
    abort: function(){},
    open: function(){},
    send: function(){this.onreadystatechange();}
}});
```

```html
<input type="text" name="brand" id="brand_input" list="brand_list" oninput="handleInput(this)" placeholder="Brand">
<datalist id="brand_list"></datalist>
```

Comment: Thanks, I've experimented a bit more and it works as expected if I focus away from the text box (i.e. click elsewhere) and then re-focus.  The issue only occurs if the results are actually loaded from a server - they didn't occur with your static example or if the datalist is loaded from a file.